# Travelling to two Schengen countries within a month

Tags: schengen, hungary, schengen-visas

I planning to travel to Hungary at the end of the July, and to Greece at the end of August. Considering a month between two travels is too short for applying a Greek visa when I return, I'd like to take care of both as early as possible. Hungarian Embassy can give an appointment only 1.5 months from now on, and there is no way that I can be certain if they will give a visa covering exactly the dates I requested or an extended period, if I get a visa. On the other hand, I can get an appointment at Greek Embassy in two weeks.

So I am planning to apply to Greece first for the period that I have planned in Greece. But I am just wondering, assuming I successfully get a visa from Greece, whether this would constitute an issue when applying to Hungary, as the period I'll apply at Hungary will be an earlier period than Greece. I'll kill my chances of getting an extended visa from Hungary for sure, but apart from that, do you think there is an issue?

Thanks!